# Symfony Swift Mailer : newInstance() is not taking variable

Tags: php, symfony1

```
 $message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Testing')
```

Here, when I pass a variable to `newInstance()` method, a mail is not sent.

```
 $var ='Testing';
 $message = Swift_Message::newInstance($var)
```

Can anyone please explain me this?

Also in Symfony framework swiftmailer is working only in actions.php. Why is it so?

Comment: that's not how you send an email using swift in symfony....you don't structure it like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to send an email using Symfony and SwiftMailer :

```
    $message = $this->getMailer()->compose(
      array('from@address.com' => 'From Name'),
      'to@address.com,
      'Subject',
      <<<EOF
      The body of the mail
      EOF
    );

    $this->getMailer()->send($message);
```

The compose() method takes four arguments and returns an email message object:

the sender email address (from);
the recipient email address(es) (to);
the subject of the message;
the body of the message.

Sending the message is then as simple as calling the send() method on the mailer instance and passing the message as an argument. As a shortcut, you can only compose and send an email in one go by using the composeAndSend() method.